# Get column name instead of column value

Tags: mysql, sql

My table `table1` is like below

```
id   d1   d2   d3   d4
1    6    7    8    9
2    13   10   11   12
3    16   17   14   15
4    19   20   21   18
```

Output table is like as

```
id   d1    d2     d3     d4   min    min_col
1    6     7      8      9    6      d1
2    13    10     11     12   10     d2
3    16    17     14     15   14     d3
4    19    20     21     18   18     d4
```

My query is like as:  `SELECT d1, d2, d3, d4, least(d1, d2, d3, d4) as min  FROM table1`

I am unable write the query; how will I get min col name instead of minimum value? How I will complete `min_col` field?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a `case` expression:

```
SELECT d1, d2, d3, d4, least(d1, d2, d3, d4) as min_value,
       (CASE  least(d1, d2, d3, d4)
            WHEN d1 THEN 'd1'
            WHEN d2 THEN 'd2'
            WHEN d3 THEN 'd3'
            WHEN d4 THEN 'd4'
        END) as min_column_name
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `case`:

```
SELECT d1, d2, d3, d4, least(d1, d2, d3, d4) as min,
       case when least(d1, d2, d3, d4)=d1 then 'd1'
            when least(d1, d2, d3, d4)=d2 then 'd2'
            when least(d1, d2, d3, d4)=d3 then 'd3'
            when least(d1, d2, d3, d4)=d4 then 'd4' 
           end as min_col
FROM table1
```

OR

```
case least(d1, d2, d3, d4)
  when d1 then 'd1'
  when d2 then 'd2'
  when d3 then 'd3'
  when d4 then 'd4' 
end as min_col
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1122c/1)

Answer (score 1):

In an RDBMS, it would be more usual to store data something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,d INT NOT NULL
,reading INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,d)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1, 1 ,      6),
(1, 2 ,      7),
(1, 3 ,      8),
(1, 4 ,      9),
(2, 1 ,     13),
(2, 2 ,     10),
(2, 3 ,     11),
(2, 4 ,     12),
(3, 1 ,     16),
(3, 2 ,     17),
(3, 3 ,     14),
(3, 4 ,     15),
(4, 1 ,     19),
(4, 2 ,     20),
(4, 3 ,     21),
(4, 4 ,     18);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---+---------+
| id | d | reading |
+----+---+---------+
|  1 | 1 |       6 |
|  1 | 2 |       7 |
|  1 | 3 |       8 |
|  1 | 4 |       9 |
|  2 | 1 |      13 |
|  2 | 2 |      10 |
|  2 | 3 |      11 |
|  2 | 4 |      12 |
|  3 | 1 |      16 |
|  3 | 2 |      17 |
|  3 | 3 |      14 |
|  3 | 4 |      15 |
|  4 | 1 |      19 |
|  4 | 2 |      20 |
|  4 | 3 |      21 |
|  4 | 4 |      18 |
+----+---+---------+
```

The query to extract the desired result could then be something like this...

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id,MIN(reading) reading FROM my_table GROUP BY id ) b 
    ON b.id = a.id 
   AND b.reading = a.reading;
+----+---+---------+
| id | d | reading |
+----+---+---------+
|  1 | 1 |       6 |
|  2 | 2 |      10 |
|  3 | 3 |      14 |
|  4 | 4 |      18 |
+----+---+---------+
```